# How can I speed-up my Webots simulation?

Tags: webots

My simulation is running correctly but is slow. How can I speed it up?

(I am part of the development team of Webots and we often get this question so I hope it will help some people!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to increase the simulation speed:

1. Use the Run button. This button runs the simulation as fast as
   possible using all the available CPU power. Otherwise, using the
   Real-Time running mode, Webots may not use all the available CPU
   power in order to slow down the simulation to match the real time.
2. Increase the value of `WorldInfo.basicTimeStep`. This field sets the
   granularity of the physics simulation. With a higher
   `WorldInfo.basicTimeStep`, the simulation becomes faster but less
   accurate. With a lower `WorldInfo.basicTimeStep`, the simulation
   becomes slower but more accurate. There is an additional
   restriction: `WorldInfo.basicTimeStep` must be chosen such as to be
   an integer divisor of the control step which is the value passed as
   a parameter to the `wb_robot_step` (or equivalent) function.
3. Decrease the value of `WorldInfo.FPS`. This field represents the
   maximum rate at which the 3D display of the main windows is
   refreshed. With a lower value, the simulation becomes faster but
   more flickering. With a higher value, the simulation becomes slower
   but less flickering.
4. Try changing the value of `WorldInfo.optimalThreadCount`. This field
   specifies how many threads are used to simulate the physics of the
   world. Depending on the world you can get a better performance by
   reducing or increasing this value. In general it is better to have a
   low number of threads for simple worlds and a bigger number of
   threads for complex worlds that include several robots physically
   independent from each other.
5. Disable unnecessary shadows. Webots uses a lot of CPU/GPU power to
   compute how and where the objects shadows are cast. But shadows are
   irrelevant for most simulation unless they should explicitly be seen
   by cameras. Unnecessary shadows can be disabled by unchecking the
   `castShadows` field of light nodes: `PointLight`, `SpotLight`, or
   `DirectionalLight`.
6. Simplify your simulation by removing unnecessary objects. In
   particular, try to minimize the number of `Physics` nodes. Avoid
   using `Solid` nodes when a `Transform` or a `Shape` node can be used
   instead.
7. Simplify the bounding objects to increase the speed of the collision
   detection. Replace complex primitives, like `IndexedFaceSet`,
   `Mesh`, `ElevationGrid` or `Cylinder` by simpler primitives, like
   `Sphere`, `Capsule`, `Box` and `Plane`. Avoid using a composition of
   primitives (in a `Group` or a `Transform`) when a single primitive
   would do the trick.
8. Set controller field to `<none>` for any `Robot` node that doesn't
   need to be controlled, instead of using the `<generic>` controller.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* BenjaminD. The way this was written, it looks like you may be associated with the product being promoted, so please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How not to be a spammer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam, but if you post good, relevant answers, then even if some (but not all) happen to be about your product, website or company, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose any affiliation in your answers.

Comment: You mention Webots by name in a question with very few details and then immediately give a long, detailed answer. If you work for Webots that's fine, iRobot and ROS representatives are offering tech support here as well, but please add your relationship to your profile and also disclose that information here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have made the appropriate changes.

We often get this question in DM or on our discord. I am posting it here so that it is better indexed and people can find the answer more easily.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminD, and welcome to *Robotics*.
You may want to check out [Olivier Michel](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/17975/olivier-michel?tab=profile)'s profile for a good example of what a full disclosure profile looks like.